# can I use interior-point method to solve binary decision problem?

Tags: optimization

I have an optimization problem formulated as follows.
Let optimization function be defined as:

maximize $\sum_j \sum_w f(_{,}\cdot \mbox{}) + g(_{,})$

subject to:  $\sum_w _{,}\cdot _{,} \cdot _{,} \leq _ \left(\forall , \forall \right)$

is a binary valued decision variables.

Both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are linear functions and constraint is also linear but unfortunately decision variable $x_{w,j}$ is binary valued.

I am confused if I can use interior-point method to solve it?

Thanks,

raza

Comment: This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 1):

Interior point methods are for continuous LPs (and related problems). They could be used to solve relaxations inside a branch-and-bound framework. However often Simplex is used there because it has better capabilities to continue from a previous point (or rather basis in LP terminology).